# Java prog piped and returned immediately

Tags: java, shell, pipe

I have a Java program that prints to stdout. If the output is piped to, say, `head` the shell doesn't return immediately after head has done its job, instead it waits for the Java program to complete all its work.

So my question is: How can I write the Java program so that the shell returns immediately, just like `cat ... | head`?

This is an example for what I mean:

Here the shell returns immediately as `head` takes no time to print the first ten line, no matter how big `bigfile.txt` is:

```
time cat bigfile.txt | head
...
real    0m0.079s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Here instead the first ten lines are quickly printed but the shell doesn't return until all the file is processed:

```
time java -jar DummyReader.jar bigfile.txt | head
...
real    0m18.720s
user    0m16.936s
sys     0m2.212s
```

`DummyReader.jar` is as simple as I could make it:

```
import java.io.*;

public class DummyReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));   
        String line;
        while((line= br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

My settings:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-10M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

On MacOS 10.6.8

Comment: So, you basically want `head` to _kill_ your Java program after it printed those first 10 lines?

Comment: @ tobias_k yes, that's right, I want to head (or whatever is downstream) to kill the java program.

Comment: I'm not sure this is how `head` works. Maybe you'll rather have to write your own "killing head" function. Or pass a parameter to your Java script, telling it to stop after x lines.

Comment: @tobias_k As I as said, the first ten lines are printed by head (nearly) immediately, that's good. However, the shell doesn't return until all the file is processed, which in my example means waiting ~18s.

Comment: On a POSIX system (Unix, Linux, etc.), the OS handles this by sending a SIGPIPE signal to cat when it tries to write more data after head has closed its side of the pipe.  I'm not sure why your Java program isn't catching this signal and aborting.

Comment: @Russell Reed,  I edited my question to include java and OS version if that can help. Thanks again for answer and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just because you're not checking for errors after the println call.  Here's a revised version that does stop.  It will be slower, though, because checkError() flushes any output that has been buffered so far.

There may be other ways to get notified about the error without the slowdown.  I've seen some code that explicitly handles the SIGPIPE signal, but I don't know if that's the best way to do it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class DummyReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));   
        String line;
        int linecount = 0;
        while((line= br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            if (System.out.checkError())
            {
                System.err.println("Got some sort of error in the output stream");
                break;
            }
            linecount++;
        }
        br.close();
        System.err.println("Read " + linecount + " lines.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I asked for. I'll see how bad the slow down you mention is...